# how to read url data

Tags: python

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

class TrakHtml(db.Model):
  hawb = db.StringProperty(required=False)
  htmlData = db.TextProperty()

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    Traks = list()
    Traks.append('93332134')
    #Traks.append('91779831')
    #Traks.append('92782244')
    #Traks.append('38476214')

    for st in Traks :
      trak = TrakHtml()
      trak.hawb = st
      url = 'http://etracking.cevalogistics.com/eTrackResultsMulti.aspx?sv='+st

      result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
      self.response.out.write(result.read())

      ***trak.htmlData = result.read()
      trak.put()
      #self.response.out.write(st)

def main():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                       debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I am getting error at ***line it is not reading url data.

Comment: Giant text is giant. You have my attention?

Comment: Please remove the copyright notice and any other code not directly related to your problem to make it easier to read.

Comment: Actually, posting the copyright notice is a very tricky thing to do here on SO: We are already using a license for all content posted here. I'm not sure you may change that...

Answer (score 3):

You have read the result twice (once in `self.responce.out.write` and once a line below).
Store the value as a string first:

```
htmlData = result.read()
self.response.out.write(htmlData)
trak.htmlData = htmlData
```

I would expect `result.read()` to move to the end of the `result` stream - think of it like a book: Reading a book, you flip page by page. When you get to the end, trying to read gets difficult - unless you rewind to the beginning.

Also, please state the error message - that is often a tremendous help in diagnosing a problem!